# Menu Flyout - Unexpected constant condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone help me with this problem? I want those internal links not to be opened in a new window tab. If I only have one item in the code it works fine, but as soon as i add another link i.e. 'governance' it throws me this error:

```
246:89  error    Unexpected constant condition                           no-constant-condition
```

Here is the code:

```
export default function Menu(props) {
  return (
    <StyledMenu tabIndex={0}>
      <StyledMenuTitle>
        <span style={{ marginRight: '0.25rem' }}>{props.data.name} </span>
        <MenuFlyout>
          {props.data.sublinks.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <StyledMenuItem tabindex={index} key={index}>
-> 246          {item.link.split('/').slice(-1)[0] === 'about', 'governance', 'people', 'blog' ? ( 
                  <StyledExternalLink href={item.link}>
                    <StyledTitle>{item.name}</StyledTitle>
                  </StyledExternalLink>
                ) : (
                  <StyledExternalLink href={item.link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    <StyledTitle>{item.name}</StyledTitle>
                    {item.description && <StyledDescription>{item.description}</StyledDescription>}
                  </StyledExternalLink>
                )}
              </StyledMenuItem>
            )
          })}
        </MenuFlyout>
      </StyledMenuTitle>
    </StyledMenu>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
someValue === 'about', 'governance', 'people', 'blog' ? 'x' : 'y'
```

is interpreted as 4 separate expressions, like:

```
someValue === 'about';  // returns true or false
'governance';           // returns 'governance'
'people';               // returns 'people'
'blog' ? 'x' : 'y';     // returns 'x'
```

So basically the first 3 are just useless expressions, because you don't do anything with the returned values.

The last one is the actually used value in your code, but it always returns `'x'`, because `'blog'` is always *truthy*.

So you could just replace the whole condition `'blog' ? 'x' : 'y';` by just the value `'x'` in your code.

Your code, including the "useless" one, is valid Javascript, but some code validation tool you are using, probably [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-constant-condition), doesn't allow a condition that will always return the same value, because obviously you wouldn't need a condition at all in such cases.